# How to show that the "bing's house with two rooms" is contractible?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, examples

I can't image this, Someone can give a clear illustration?

Comment: This question seems too localized.

Comment: Ken Baker has put up some beautiful images here: http://sketchesoftopology.wordpress.com/2010/03/25/bings-house/

Comment: An update to jc's comment above: Ken Baker made a subsequent post that describes a deformation retraction: http://sketchesoftopology.wordpress.com/2010/06/23/the-deformation-retraction-of-bings-house/

Comment: I am confused by the very first step in Ken's illustrations. I don't see how this sequence https://www.flickr.com/photos/sketchesoftopology/4644072542/ is a continuous deformation that stays within the original complex. Could someone comment on that? (The remaining steps are then straightforward.)

Answer (score 2):

This is covered in Chapter 0 (the introductory chapter) of Algebraic Topology by Allen Hatcher.

Comment: Yes, but is not clearly for me.

Comment: Hatcher gives a pretty lucid description.  What part of it is not clear?  He suggests visualizing a thickening of the space as made out of clay: have you tried using playdough?  I have resorted to playdough many times when my visual imagination failed me.

Comment: May be a good exercise is to take a loop which is looking non-trivial and try to see that it is contractible. 

Comment: Sorry, my imagination is really poor,"hollowing out the chamber" is not clear.

Comment: It sounds like this is a language issue.  Imagine a drinking glass full of wax.  It's a solid object.  By melting the wax and draining the liquid wax, you in effect "hollow out the chamber" -- the chamber being the glass full of wax.  The hollow chamber is the empty glass. 

Comment: But,I want a proof in mathematical style!!!

Comment: Parameterizing those maps is going to be a painful endeavor.

Comment: You can realize the deformation-retraction as a sequence (concatenation) of "elementary collapse" operations. In particular you can write the map as a piecewise construction, made of composites of rational polynomial functions.  These elementary collapses appear in many places in Hatcher's book -- the main construction in Proposition 0.16 of Chapter 0 (page 15) is the first such explicit construction, I think. 

Comment: Well, can you tell me if remove the two vertical rectangles (‘support walls’ for the two tunnels),it remains contractible?

Comment: The main issue you seem to be having is that Hatcher is assuming a certain level of comfort with linear-algebraic constructions.  A good way to achieve this level of maturity would be to work through much of the point-set and fundamental-group problems in a book like Munkres. 

Comment: If you remove the support walls I think this new space has to have a fundamental group.  Think about a loop that runs up the "external" wall and down the tunnel. 

Comment: Ok,Thanks for your advice, maybe this is not a "problem" for you.

Comment: You might want to take a look at Marshall Cohen's book "A Course in Simple Homotopy Theory".  He's quite explicit about these sorts of details. 