# Again about Bing's house with two rooms

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, examples, gt.geometric-topology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to show that the “bing’s house with two rooms” is contractible?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17551/how-to-show-that-the-bings-house-with-two-rooms-is-contractible)

I don't know why my question is closed? here, I make my question clearly, when "hollowing out the chambers",why two vertical rectangles (are inserted to form ‘support walls’ for the two tunnels) are left ? if remove them, it remain contractible?

Comment: Read the FAQ.  You've just broken the rules.

Comment: I'll respond in the closed thread: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/17551/how-to-show-that-the-bings-house-with-two-rooms-is-contractible-closed

Comment: Sorry, I should read the FAQ first, but my question still not be sovled for me.

Comment: @gylns, I've closed this question as it's an exact duplicate of the question you asked previously.

If a question is closed, it is fine to improve it to an acceptable level and ask that it be reopened, or indeed to ask a new, better question, but it's obviously wasting everyone's time to just ask the same question again.

Comment: Ok, I am sorry!